# Prepare executable from asp.net JQuery application

Tags: iphone, asp.net, android, executable, jquery-mobile

I want to develop a mobile version of my webiste, of course with some very less features. This application will run on Iphone, Android and blackberry. What would be the better way?

1. Creating a asp.net application and deploy it on server, just like any other web application and user can access the same by visiting the link from mobile browser.
2. Creating a asp.net jQuery mobile application and provide an app for iPhone, Android and Blackberry, so that user can install it. Than fetching the web content from Web Service.

I am more intrested in approcah 2 because in this way I can provide a executable application which I can provide to the user. My problem is this that I have developed a mobile application in ASP.NET with jQuery mobile but I am unaware about how to make an app out of it.

Any idea?

**Edit1**

Is there any tutorial exists which demonstrate how can create a application in PhoneGap, whoch opens the URL in the web browser without use know that it is a web brower [*i.e. hiding the URL bar of the browser*]

Comment: I have asp.net application, I just want to create an icon in Andriod which open my application in web browser

Comment: One thing you could do is modify your main website and make the CSS "responsive" using @media queries (http://baymard.com/blog/responsive-web-design)

Answer (score 1):

Check out IISExpress or IIS embeddable web core (part of Windows 7) to distribute your application as a desktop application.

But if you want to provide an offline-style application to your mobile users that syncronizes data from a remote webserver, check out [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and [offline manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html). (this same option can also work for desktop users, gmail does something like this)

Comment: I have an asp.net application ready, but I want to create Icon for Android, Iphone which will open it in mobile. I mean I don't want my user to remember URL.

Comment: on the iphone, the magic is a combination of manifest (to let it run offline), the icon file is named `apple-touch-icon.png` [on iOS](http://www.bernskiold.com/2011/01/07/adding-an-iphoneipad-icon-for-your-website/) (Android [has a few more challenges](http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2010/06/web_app_homescreen_icons_in_android.html)), and using a [few meta tags](http://ajaxian.com/archives/iphone-full-screen-webapps) to define the app to run in full screen.

Comment: Your users will still need to save the icon to the desktop via the browser's "add to home screen" button. There may be some javascript (the classic "add favorite/bookmark" script will probably work) to do this for them.

Answer (score 1):

Several users have reported that they successfully wrapped a jquery mobile web app into a native app (multi-platform) via phonegap (http://www.phonegap.com/). I can't personally vouch for it. See discussions at http://forum.jquery.com/search/phonegap%20mobile.